# How to logout all login users in sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, session-cookies, sorcery

I am using sorcery for authentication in our site. I want to logout all login users from our site but can't find any way to logout all users.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. using timeout

   ```
   # config/initializers/sorcery.rb
   Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:session_timeout]

   # config/initializers/sorcery.rb
   Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
     config.session_timeout = 1 # This is in seconds.
     config.session_timeout_from_last_action = true # session timeout is calculated from the last valid activity. By default this is false.
   end
   ```
2. using callback

   ```
   # app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   before_action :auto_logout, if: :logged_in?
   def auto_logout
     force_forget_me!
     logout
   end
   ```
3. using current_users, add class method in user model

   ```
   # app/models/user.rb
   def self.get_current_users
     config = sorcery_config

     where("#{config.last_activity_at_attribute_name} IS NOT NULL") \
     .where("#{config.last_logout_at_attribute_name} IS NULL 
       OR #{config.last_activity_at_attribute_name} > #{config.last_logout_at_attribute_name}") \
     .where("#{config.last_activity_at_attribute_name} > ? ", config.activity_timeout.seconds.ago.utc.to_s(:db))
   end

   # call upper method anywhere (or console)
   User.get_current_users.each do |user|
     current_user = user
     before_logout!
     @current_user = nil
     reset_sorcery_session
     after_logout!(user)
   end
   ```
4. (recommend)remove session store from your disk like session_store, redis etc..and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can invalidate all sessions using `invalidate_active_sessions!`

See https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery#session-timeout

Comment: How to run this command?

Comment: Sorry, this method will delete sessions for the single user like @user.invalidate_active_sessions! This will not fit for your solution.

Comment: How about just `User.all.each {|u| u.invalidate_active_sessions! }`

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `invalidate_active_sessions!' for #<User:0x000000000fc10a70>

Comment: Hey @Haseeb - Did you find any solution regarding this problem? I want the user to be logged out from all the active sessions upon password updation.

Comment: yes you can change session_store key

Comment: Hey @Haseeb - Can you please explain the process a bit?